# Will formatting the FreeDOS partition make Windows 10 unbootable?

Tags: linux, partitioning, mbr, xubuntu, freedos

I bought a Lenovo Y700-17ISK and it came with FreeDOS on a separate partition in the beginning of the hard drive. It looked like that:

FreeDOS 1 GB - unallocated space 931 GB

Then, I installed Windows 10, creating a new partition beforehand, so it looked like that afterward:

FreeDOS 1 GB - Windows 10 300 GB - unallocated space 630 GB

I wanted to install Xubuntu alongside Windows 10, so I ran a Xubuntu installer and I was given the information that the disk is divided in the following manner:

- /dev/sda1: fat32, 1 GB, FreeDOS
- /dev/sda2: ntfs, 300 GB, *no operating system*
- /dev/sda3: ntfs, 631 GB, no operating system

I am wondering if I am able to boot Windows 10 after installing Xubuntu, for I can clearly see that no operating system was found on /dev/sda2. That's why I began thinking about removing the partition with FreeDOS and merging it with the Windows 10 partition, but I am uncertain if doing so might remove the possibility to boot Windows 10, too. After all, the FreeDOS partition is *in the beginning* of the hard drive. I am using the MBR partitioning style.

What should I do? I want to remove that unnecessary 1 GB partition (I regret that I didn't do that while installing Windows), it is a primary partition and it's also annoying for that reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physical position of partitions has nothing to do with the boot sequence. The boot code is stored in the MBR, and it then calls the bootloader at the right position on the disk, not caring about partitions.

If you want to remove this partition, I suggest you do it from Windows itself, that way if it might break anything Windows will tell you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, if I remove the FreeDOS partition and merge it with the Windows partition, making it look like Windows 10 301 GB - unallocated space 631 GB, will it be okay?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem. Once you install Xubuntu, its own bootloader (usually GRUB) will take over and overwrite the MBR anyway.

Comment: As far as I can see, the procedure of extending the Windows partition to the left might render it unbootable, but there are tools such as AOMEI Partition Assistant that can handle it. However, I just thought of something different... I was planning to give some swap space to Xubuntu, just in case it was needed. This laptop has 16 GB RAM, but I read somewhere that it's always better to give some swap to Linux. So... If I reformat the FreeDOS partition to swap and tell the Xubuntu installer to use it, it still should be fine, yeah?

Comment: Okay, never mind, I just installed Xubuntu. What is curious, it turned out (what I was actually quite expecting) that it's FreeDOS who boots Windows.

Comment: Linux Swap partitions make sense only if they're 5GB or more, especially with large RAM such as yours. Anyway, I'm glad your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take a look at [BIOS/MBR-based hard drive partitions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/configure-biosmbr-based-hard-drive-partitions) of Windows.

> Partition layout
>
> If you install Windows using a bootable USB key made by Windows Imaging and Configuration Designer (ICD), it creates the following layout by default: a system partition, a Windows partition, and a recovery tools partition.
>
> [image: Partition layout]

So, no, deleting the FreeDOS shouldn't be any problem to Windows.